# Input only id in table with php

Tags: php, sql, forms, select

I'm trying to enter the value of the select in a table, but I just need to put the id `($row['id_eq'])` the other value is simply indicative

How could I make the insert representing that the selected `$row` only enter the `id_eq`?

**Code here:**

```
<div class="form-row">

    <?php

    include("../../conexion/conexion.php");

    $query1  = "SELECT id_eq, name_eq FROM equipos";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query1);
    ?>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2" id="Team1">
        <label for="Team1"><b>Equipo 1</b></label>
        <!-- Menú select llamando a datos de una tabla de MySQL -->

        <select class="form-control" value="Team1" name="Team1">
            <option selected>Equipo 1</option>

            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):; ?>

                <option><?php echo $row['id_eq'], " ", $row['name_eq']; ?></option>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $row['id_eq']?>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple, just set the value of the input and display the "indicative" value as text of the option:
Here is an example;

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id_eq']?>"><?php echo $row['name_eq'];?></option>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going crazy to find something so easy